# TypeORM - Creating two Foreign Keys in the same table that also reference the same PK

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, foreign-keys, typeorm

I am utilizing **TypeORM 0.3.10** with **Postgres** and attempting to generate and then run a Migration with **ts-node-commonjs**, but I am unable to do so because two FKs in the same table are referencing the same PK. This is my DB:
[image]

The two FKs inside Transactions need to reference an Account id, albeit they will reference different ones for each Transaction entry. The way I have my entities setup is the following:

**Account.ts**

```
import { Column, Entity, OneToMany, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";
import { Transaction } from "./Transaction";

@Entity('accounts')
export class Account {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number

  @Column({ type: 'decimal', precision: 12, scale: 2, default: 0.00 })
  balance: number

  @OneToMany(() => Transaction, (transaction) => transaction.account)
  transactions: Transaction[]
}
```

**Transaction.ts**

```
import { Column, Entity, JoinColumn, ManyToOne, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";
import { Account } from "./Account";

@Entity('transactions')
export class Transaction {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number

  @ManyToOne(() => Account, (account) => account.transactions)
  @JoinColumn([
    { name: 'debitedAccountId', referencedColumnName: "id" },
    { name: 'creditedAccountId', referencedColumnName: "id" }
  ])
  account: Account
  

  @Column({ type: 'decimal', precision: 12, scale: 2, default: 100.00 })
  value: number

  @Column({ type: 'date' })
  createdAt: Date
}
```

It can generate the Migration just fine with:

```
typeorm-ts-node-commonjs -d ./src/data-source.ts migration:generate ./src/migrations/default
```

But when it comes to actually running it with:

```
typeorm-ts-node-commonjs -d ./src/data-source.ts migration:run
```

Is when I get an Error.

> Migration "default1668728216714" failed, error: foreign key referenced-columns list must not contain duplicates
> *query: ROLLBACK*
> **Error during migration run:**
> QueryFailedError: foreign key referenced-columns list must not contain duplicates

I have also tried to setup `@JoinColumn` in a different way:

```
  @JoinColumn([
    { name: 'debitedAccountId', referencedColumnName: "id" },
  ])
  @JoinColumn([
    { name: 'creditedAccountId', referencedColumnName: "id" }
  ])
  account: Account
```

But still to no avail. I have also tried to disable Foreign Key constraints via `createForeignKeyConstraints: false` just like the Documentation says but it doesn't really solve my issue, unsurprisingly.

I've been combing through said [documentation here](https://typeorm.io/many-to-one-one-to-many-relations) as well as on the sections about Decorators proprieties, RelationsFAQ and whatnot but can't seem to find a solution for my problem. Other forum posts also always have a different setup (usually with composite PKs) that doesn't quite apply to my issue, but I have tried their suggestion regardless and nothing worked.

I believe I can make the "raw query" that generates the DB the way I want it to, but I can't get TypeORM to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found a solution. I was trying to declare only one OneToMany relation for two ManyToOne relations. So instead of using default decorator values, I'd need to specify which Column either side is referencing to. So in the end it will look like this:

**--Account.ts**

```
@OneToMany(() => Transaction, (transaction) => transaction.creditedAccount)
creditedAccount: Transaction[]

@OneToMany(() => Transaction, (transaction) => transaction.debitedAccount)
debitedAccount: Transaction[]
```

*note: I am omitting the "Id" at the end of both keys because TypeORM already adds them by default. And because that's what I want I am unsure how I'd go around avoiding it for now.*

**-- Transaction.ts**

```
@ManyToOne(() => Account, (account) => account.creditedAccount)
@JoinColumn([
  { referencedColumnName: "id" }
])
creditedAccount: Account

@ManyToOne(() => Account, (account) => account.debitedAccount)
@JoinColumn([
  { referencedColumnName: "id" }
])
debitedAccount: Account
```

I am not 100% sure this will work without a hitch because I couldn't quite find anything like this in the Documentation nor in other forum posts. Until further edit from myself, or perhaps someone else's answer with a working (or just better) solution, assume this has solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, where my game has a PlayerOne and a PlayerTwo, and the player wants to know all it's games, regardless if it was playerOne or playerTwo.

I ended up doing a custom getter on my Player side.

### Game

```js
@ManyToOne(() => UserEntity)
playerOne: UserEntity;

@ManyToOne(() => UserEntity)
playerTwo: UserEntity;
```

### Player

```js
  @OneToMany(() => GameEntity, (game) => game.playerOne)
  gamesAsPlayerOne: GameEntity[];

  @OneToMany(() => GameEntity, (game) => game.playerTwo)
  gamesAsPlayerTwo: GameEntity[];

  // combine and sort games
  get allGames(): GameEntity[] {
    const combinedGames = [
      ...(this.gamesAsPlayerOne || []),
      ...(this.gamesAsPlayerTwo || []),
    ];
    return combinedGames.sort(
      (a, b) => a.createdAt.getTime() - b.createdAt.getTime(),
    );
  }
```